# winjs: textbox content validation and alerts using popup message dialog box?

Tags: javascript, validation, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have the form with textbox and button. I have 454 html files, and from that textbox i gather the number and shown the respective entered number's html files. Here is the problem. If the user enters in between 1 and 454, respective file is opened. Else, nothing happened. but, i have a Message Dialog code for that.

HTML Code:

```
    <div class="win-content win-settings-section">
         <input type="text" id="number" />
         <button type="button" id="buttonClick">Show !</button>
         <div id="def-content"></div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript Code :

```
function buttonClick() 
{
 var getFile = document.getElementById("number").value;
 if (getFile < 455 && getFile > 0) 
     {
     var output = new WinJS.UI.HtmlControl(document.getElementById("def-content"), { uri: '/def/f' + getFile + '.html' });
     }
 else 
     {
     Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Expected Value Range: 1 to 454.");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really asked a question, but Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog() only creates the popup message. In order to show it you need to call the showAsync() method like this.

```
function buttonClick() 
{
   var getFile = document.getElementById("number").value;
   if (getFile < 455 && getFile > 0) {
      var output = new WinJS.UI.HtmlControl(document.getElementById("def-content"), { uri: '/def/f' + getFile + '.html' });
   } else {
      var popup = Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Expected Value Range: 1 to 454.");
      popup.showAsync();
   }
}
```